# Групировка Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Как сделать групировку datagrid?
Мне надо групировка по одному столбцу.
Вот мой DataGrid:

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [Table1] ORDER BY [Id] ASC", conn);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt);
                PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Столбец 1");
                view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = view.SourceCollection;
}
```

Но это неработает выводиться как обычная таблица.
Приблизительный вид групировки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот моя таблица в базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

СУБД MS SQL, вот код создания таблицы

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Table1] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Столбец 1] FLOAT (53) NULL,
    [Столбец 2] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Столбец 3] IMAGE NULL,
    [qwwesfas] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```

Вывод таблицы DataGrid:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думаю проблема тут new PropertyGroupDescription("Столбец 1") вам нужно указать именно название колонки, а нее ее хидер. Я не думаю что у вас колонка называется  Столбец 1, во первых потому что в названиях свойств не может быть пробелов. Если у вас авто-генерация колонок, то ее название будет аналогично колонке из базы

Comment: @PavelPopov Добавил к вопросу свою таблицу из базы.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что название колонки в базе может содержать пробел ?) Чет не верится. Можете показать SQL запрос но без * именно перечислить в нем название колонок ?

Comment: Я думаю там что то типа Столбец_1

Comment: @PavelPopov Я создавал таблицу и там содержится пробел в названии столбца

Comment: ок, что за СУБД ? и можете показать SQL запрос создания этой таблицы ?

Comment: @PavelPopov Написал в вопросе

Comment: Я проверил в MS SQL...действительно создается)) даже не могу представить зачем это ....но зато к этой колонке можно обратится только [Колонка 1] т.е. без кв. скобок она не доступна. НО название колонки в гриде все равно не может содержать пробел. Возможно она там как Колонка_1. А вообще по хорошему создайте таб. с названиями колонок на анг. и без пробелов, и будет вам счастье)

Comment: @PavelPopov Посмотрите добавил картинку Datagrid. И название с пробелом

Comment: @PavelPopov Указал столбец без пробелов также не работает.